# Understanding ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

I have some trouble understanding ordinary differential equations.

---

Wikipedia gives this definition:

Let $\,\Omega \subseteq \mathbb {R} \times \left(\mathbb {R} ^{m}\right)^{n+1},\,\,n\in \mathbb {N}\,$ and $\,f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb {R} ^{m}$ continuos. Then

$f\left(x,y,y',\ldots ,y^{(n)}\right)=0$

is an ordinary differential equation. We call n-times differentiable functions $y\,\colon I\to \mathbb {R} ^{m}$, that "are true" in the given ordinary differential equation for a certain interval $I\subset \mathbb {R}$.

---

Now first thing: German Wikipedia and English Wikipedia give the same definition, except that English Wikipedia says $y\,\colon I\to \mathbb {R}$ instead of $y\,\colon I\to \mathbb {R} ^{m}$.

So what is right? The case of English Wiki doesn't make sense to me, because we need to pass an element of $\Omega$ to $f$, so $x\in\mathbb{R}$ but $(y,y',...,y^{(n)})$ must be in $(\mathbb{R}^m)^{n+1}$.

But I also don't understand why the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb {R} \times \left(\mathbb {R} ^{m}\right)^{n+1}$ (or a subset of that). Because: How can $y^{(k)}$ be an element of $\mathbb {R} ^{m}$? It is, since it's a derivative, a linear function.

Or do I have to understand the equation this way?

$f\left(x,y(z),y'(z),\ldots ,y^{(n)}(z)\right)=0\,\,$ for all $\,\,z \in I$.

---

If I look at a concrete ODE, e.g. this one:

$y' = a\cdot y + b$

Then $f(x,y) = a(x) \cdot y + b(x)$ (if we regard it as an explicit ODE), right?

But how should I understand that equation? This way?

$y'(z) = F(x,y) = a(x)\cdot y(z) + b(x)$ for all $z \in I$

Or this way?

$y'(x) = F(x,y) = a(x)\cdot y(x) + b(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now first thing: German Wikipedia and English Wikipedia give the same definition, except that English Wikipedia says $y\,\colon I\to \mathbb {R}$ instead of $y\,\colon I\to \mathbb {R} ^{m}$.

The English version is a typo, it should be $y:I\to\mathbb R^m$.

> But I also don't understand why the definitionset of $f$ is $\mathbb {R} \times \left(\mathbb {R} ^{m}\right)^{n+1}$ (or a subset of that). Because: How can $y^{(k)}$ be an element of $\mathbb {R} ^{m}$? It is, since it's a derivative, a linear function.

Since the domain of $y$ is an interval in $\mathbb R$, we can compute derivative using the formula from elementary calculus :
$$y'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \in\mathbb R^m$$
On the other hand, its differential at a point $\text dy(x) $ is a linear map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^m$, which is uniquely determined by $\text df(x) \cdot 1 = y'(x)$$.

> Or do I have to understand the equation this way?
> $$f\left(x,y(z),y'(z),\ldots ,y^{(n)}(z)\right)=0\qquad\text{for all}\quad z \in I$$

The variable of the unkown function $y$ is often omitted. The equation is understood as :
$$\forall x\in I, f\big(x,y(x),\ldots,y^{(n)}(x)\big )= 0$$

The equation $y' = ay +b$ corresponds to the function :
$$f(x,y,y') = y' - a(x)y -b(x)$$
with all the variable written out, the equation reads :
$$\forall x\in I, y'(x) = a(x) y(x) + b(x)$$